# Curved corner border for a div

Tags: html, css

I need to build a div with curved corner border, with out using any images in the corner. Is it possible?

I dont want to insert curved images in the corner, Please help me regarding this.

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie) - a very simple cross-browser CSS3 code.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to rely on webkit and mozilla browsers, you can use the following css commands:

```
.radius {
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

Details can be viewed [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).

info on the CSS2 spec border-radius can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/#the-border-radius)

These unfortunately do not work for ie.

you could go a javascript route for IE only by using [niftycube](http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html) which has the added benefit of supporting column height leveling without problems.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.curvycorners.net/

Try this library out, it did wonders for me! It is a tested cross browser solution.

Comment: That site seems [down](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.curvycorners.net). [Last project update](http://code.google.com/p/curvycorners/source/list) was on Mar, 2011. Project is hosted on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/curvycorners/).

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS to achieve rounded corners in modern browsers...

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

[Handy Generator](http://border-radius.com/)

This is known as [*progressive enhancement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). IMO, this is better than images and or CSS tricks with margins and borders. Unless you absolutely must have rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I wrote that you're welcome to use if you like it. It renders a rounded-corner box of any dimensions with a background color but not a border around the entire box. It is for white page backgrounds, but that can be changed by editing the border color in the c1,c2 & c3 styles.

```
.rounded {background-color:#f1f0f1}
.rounded .inner {padding:8px 10px 8px 12px}
.rounded .c1 {height:1px;line-height:1px;font-size:1px;border-width: 0px 4px 0px 4px;border-color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;padding:0px}
.rounded .c2 {height:1px;line-height:1px;font-size:1px;display:block;border-width: 0px 2px 0px 2px;border-color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;padding:0px}
.rounded .c3 {height:2px;line-height:1px;font-size:1px;display:block;border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;border-color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;padding:0px}


   <div class="rounded" style="width:200px;height:100px">
    <div class="c1"></div><div class="c2"></div><div class="c3"></div>
        <div class="inner">
        -- Content Here --
        </div>
        <div class="c3"></div><div class="c2"></div><div class="c1"></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd use a jQuery plugin to handle rounded corners. Here's the list of available rounded corner plugins on the jQuery site: http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/189