# How do I create a circle or square with just CSS - with a hollow center?

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

It should just basically be an outline of the square or circle - that I can style accordingly (i.e. change the color to whatever I want, change the thickness of the border, etc.)

I would like to apply that circle or square over something else (like an image or something) and the middle part should be hollowed out, so you can see the image beneath the square or circle.

I would prefer for it to be mainly CSS + HTML.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try This

```css
div.circle {
  -moz-border-radius: 50px/50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 50px/50px;
  border: solid 21px #f00;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

div.square {
  border: solid 21px #f0f;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img/>
</div>
 <hr/>
<div class="square">
  <img/>
</div>
```

[More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-radius)

Answer (score 20):

You can use special characters to make lots of shapes.  Examples: 
http://jsfiddle.net/martlark/jWh2N/2/

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hollow square</td>
    <td>&#9633;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>solid circle</td>
    <td>&bull;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>open circle</td>
    <td>&#3664;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[image]

Many more can be found here: [HTML Special Characters](http://brucejohnson.ca/SpecialCharacters.html)

Answer (score 8):

i don't know of a simple css(2.1 standard)-only solution for circles, but for squares you can do easily:

```
.squared {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

then, use the following html code:

```
<img src="…" alt="an image " class="squared" />
```

Comment: This is interesting...I just don't like using the `<img>` tag. I prefer using a regular `<div>` like the above solution. Thanks though. By the way, I never downvoted. I upvoted :)

Comment: @marcamillion: i only used an image tag because it really does not matter. (quote: »I would like to apply that circle or square over something else (like an **image** or something)«) – you can of course use a div, a paragraph, or anything else. just apply the class and style it to your liking

Comment: @nick because the div was made for that (a default container) as opposed to an img tag made to pull images. I know it doesn't have to be used what it was made for, but I would prefer to do that :) @Knittl....I think you misunderstood what I was looking for. I am not looking for a square border. I would like to create a square that is say 50px X 50px, that is just an outline. Like Caspar did in his example for the circle - I just modified that for a square. That's what I was looking for. Now all I will do is add z-index to it, above the elements I want it to be on top of. That's all :)

Comment: ok, you said “apply the square to …”, so it wasn't really clear to me. glad you found a solution to your problem

Answer (score 7):

If you want your div to keep it's circular shape even if you change its width/height (using js for instance) set the radius to 50%. Example:
css:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%/50%; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Circle Time! :) Easy way of making a circle with a hollow center : use border-radius, give the element a border and no background so you can see through it :

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width:100px;
    border:solid black 2px;
}

body{
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there is no cross-browser compatible way to make a circle with CSS & HTML only.

For the square I guess you could make a div with a border and a z-index higher than what you are putting it over.  I don't understand why you would need to do this, when you could just put a border on the image or "something" itself.

If anyone else knows how to make a circle that is cross browser compatible with CSS & HTML only, I would love to hear about it!

@Caspar Kleijne border-radius does not work in IE8 or below, not sure about 9.

Comment: IE9 will support it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie

Comment: I didn't figure it would, but I hadn't tested it myself, so I didn't want to say for sure, surprising that IE has finally decided to support something that everyone wanted them to. :D

Comment: there are no browser requirements set by the OP. (perhaps it is for fun or corporate intranet)? The OP wanted a circle in html and CSS so he gets what he asked for ;)

Comment: I am trying to do 'tagging' functionality, like facebook. Where you can tag a section of an image or some other element. That's why someone might want to do this. Also, the CSS2/3 border-radius implementation is good enough for me.

Comment: I would suggest instead of using an extra parent div over the item you are "tagging" that you add a CSS class with the required css to the item you want "tagged".

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after finding this questions I found these examples on CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Copied so you don't have to click

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
/* Cleaner, but slightly less support: use "50%" as value */
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

There are many other shape examples in the above link, but you will have to test for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In case of circle all you need is one div, but in case of hollow square you need to have 2 divs.
The divs are having a display of ***inline-block*** which you can change accordingly. Live Codepen link: [Click Me](https://codepen.io/worstfear/pen/YzPNEaR)

In case of circle all you need to change is the ***border*** properties and the ***dimensions***(width and height) of circle. If you want to change color just change the border color of ***hollow-circle***.

In case of the square ***background-color*** property needs to be changed depending upon the background of page or the element upon which you want to place the ***hollow-square***. Always keep the ***inner-circle*** dimension small as compared to the **hollow-square**. If you want to change color just change the background-color of ***hollow-square***. The ***inner-circle*** is centered upon the ***hollow-square*** using the ***position, top, left, transform properties*** just don't mess with them.

Code is as follows:

```css
/* CSS Code */

.hollow-circle {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* Use this */
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  /* or */
  /* Shorthand Property */
  /* border: 5px solid #000; */
}

.hollow-square {
  position: relative;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}

.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML Code -->

<div class="hollow-circle">
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="hollow-square">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```