# CSS Text Editing

Tags: css, text, editing, geometry

Hey guys I have a question, I plan on making a website for a friend that wants a nice description about them, for in terms of design they want something like this:

```
                              dsdsdsds
                           sdsdsdsdsdsdsd
                        sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsds
                     sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd
                    sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd
                     sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdd
                       sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd
                          sdsdsdsdsdsdsds
                            sdsdsdsdsdsd
                               sdsdsdsd
```

So basically small line of text at the start, and increase for the middle, then decrease in size near the end, so basically a circle type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One bad way is to have a fixed number of lines (and maybe no word-wrap). Just do spans and have the id's of each span have a pre-defined width.

A better (somewhat) way is to do something along these lines [css circle via stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815732/how-do-i-create-a-circle-or-square-with-just-css-with-a-hollow-center). You may have to tweak it though (and I haven't tried it), but you could play around to see of you like it.

I'm pretty certain the latter is the way you would go, but the ease of constructing it may not be overly fast.

Good luck!

Comment: I should state that I assumed this css-bit would be re-used. So, yes, if this is only for one person and the wording won't change, then Bert's answer would be quite good-enough.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around in Google, I have found this:
[CSS Text Wrapper](http://www.csstextwrap.com/examples.php)

It involves javascript, but you dont really need to know javascript in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve that use

```
<pre></pre>
```

then apply the css to the text.

Its the easiest way to do that.