# rounded corner not working on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I used rounded corner and gradient. it's working good on firefox but rounded corner not working on IE. IE rounded corner only working when I remove gradient css. Please help me.

```
    <h2 id="user_comments">9. User Comments and Notes</h2>    
        h2 {
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius:8px;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #A0ABBF, #DEDEDE, #A0ABBF) repeat scroll 0 0 #A0ABBF;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(StartColorStr='#DEDEDE', EndColorStr='#A0ABBF');  /* IE6,IE7 */
       -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#DEDEDE', EndColorStr='#A0ABBF')"; /* IE8 */ 
        border:2px solid #A0ABBF;
        font-size:16px;
        letter-spacing:1px;
        margin-top:36px;
        padding:0 1em;
        position:relative;
        }
```

Firefox: [image]
 IE:
 [image]

Comment: Which "IE" are we talking about here?

Comment: Bookmark this site for future reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but where in the code you posted does it give rounded corners for IE?  I see -moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius, but that's all...

Comment: May I also point out that you're only using the Mozilla and Webkit specific border radius rules? Of course they won't work in IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE7 and IE8 don't support `border-radius`.

[IE9 will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie/3782946#3782946).

There are JavaScript hacks, most involve a heap of 1px elements absolutely positioned or use SVG.

You can also images.

I'd just leave it as is, and consider > IE8 and other browsers are getting the *progressive enhancement*.