# IE9 Rendering elements with opacity, border-radius or cufon

Tags: internet-explorer-9, opacity, cufon, css

Please visit [wellcarestrategies.com](http://www.wellcarestrategies.com) to see what I'm talking about. Compare the rendering of IE9 with Firefox and notice the following problems:

1. IE9 is adding outlines around portions of elements that have opacity defined on them.
2. IE9 is also displaying cufon type with major artifacts or distortion.
3. IE9 is adding white lines in the corners of elements with border-radius defined.

This seems to be a recent occurence, perhaps since a recent update to IE9. Has anyone experienced similar problems? Any ideas on solutions?

Many thanks

### Update

Perhaps it has to do with my virtual machine that I'm using?

Comment: Hi curiouser, It seems to render fine in IE9 atm. What did you do? I have the same issue atm.

Comment: Apologie for the delay, but I'm almost certain it is an issue with Windows 7 Hardware accelerated graphics in VMWare Fusion on a Mac. I'm pretty sure when you disable Graphics acceleration in system preferences of win7 the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with VMWare Fusion 4 for Mac and Windows 7 Hardware accelerated graphics. After disabling the Win7 Hardware accelerated graphics within Win7, all is well.