# Border Radius on Input Elements in IE8+

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to get a border radius no matter what I do. I am running the latest internet explorer and nothing is happening. I have gone into the developer tools and set the rendering to ie9 and it still refuses to read:

```
  border-radius: 4px;
```

As far as I understand, ie9 does in fact support this CSS3 element. Am I do doing wrong? I am trying to get the browsers to see more or less the same page. Any suggesions? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321224/ie9-border-radius-shorthand-not-supported and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784999/border-radius-not-working-in-ie9 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381446/ie9-border-radius and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie !

Comment: To clarify: you need to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your page OR add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` inside the `<head>` tag. This will tell IE9 that you actually want to use the standards mode (with CSS3 and stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some of the following:

```
border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
```

Be sure that these items are in the correct css class you are trying to apply to the form element.

Comment: webkit and moz have absolutly nothing to do with IE, they stand for safari/chrome and mozille. And adding the extra zero's actualy produces a different effect...

Comment: AND the standard-conform declaration always should be the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to define all border properties. Here is an example;

```
input{
border: solid 4px #06C;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
height: 40px;
width: 100px
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/aYMZz/)*** is a working Live Demo, running smooth in my IE9.

Note: **[Here](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/)** is a list of browsers supporting CSS3 and others will not.

Answer (score -1):

YOU have a [website for create border-radius css code](http://border-radius.com/)

```
border-radius : 4px; // for new ie, opera, chrome, firefox
```

is a **new** W3C specification for **new** browser,

if you can use border radius for old browser, you can use

```
-webkit-border-radius : 4px; // for old chrome, old safari
-moz-border-radius : 4px;  // for old firefox
-o-border-radius : 4px;  // for old opera version
```

for old ie version, you want to use [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: YOU need to [do more research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie). Your proposed solution won't help IE8 at all, and IE9 supports rounded corners natively without a prefix.

Comment: I know, I've edit my answer for specify old ans new browser, but, IE9 is a NEW ie browser... it's normally to support border-radius... and I have explain with CSS PIE, border radius was supported with IE 7, 8...