# IE9 issue border radius and linear gradient

Tags: css

I have used CSS PIE and filters to overcome the issue of border radius and linear gradient in IE9 with CSS, but I am not satisfied with the result. Is there any way to implement border radius with linear gradient?

Answer (score 6):

Yup: implement the linear gradient in IE9 using an SVG background image.

A few of the online gradient generators will provide this option in their output. See e.g. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ (check the “IE 9 support” checkbox underneath the results checkbox).

Thankfully, SVG backgrounds are clipped by `border-radius` in IE 9, unlike gradients implemented with `filter`.

Comment: @SUJITHREDDY: no need to apologise, but if you’d like some help, you will need to show us the code that isn’t working. Could you post it to http://jsfiddle.net/?