# IE9 css :first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors, internet-explorer-9

I have a css rule like this in my css file:

```
.Island_VerticalMenu:first-child { width: 100% }
```

However, when I view it in the developer tool of IE9, it looks like this:

```
:first-child.Island_VerticalMenu { width: 100% }
```

and doesnt work.

If I manually change it to the first one in the developer tool, it is applied correctly.

Any known workaround?

Update:

```
* > .Island_VerticalMenu:first-child { width: 100% }
* > table.Island_VerticalMenu:first-child { width: 100% }
table.Island_VerticalMenu:first-child { width: 100% }
table.Island_VerticalMenu > span  { width: 100% }
.Island_VerticalMenu:first-child { width: 100% }
.Island_VerticalMenu:first-child span { width: 100% }
.Island_VerticalMenu  span:first-of-type { width: 100% }
.Island_VerticalMenu > span { width: 100% }
```

None of these work

PS. I am in compatibility mode

Comment: I ended up solving it via javascript

Comment: I don't think these will work at all in compatibility mode. If you are doing CSS3 addressing developing on a local file, you have to click on Tools ->' compatibility view settings' in the IE9 menu and then unclick the checkbox that says 'display interanet sites in compatibility view'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this may be it's helpful to you

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

Comment: Didn't help. It must be something else