# span width not properly setting in ie9 but working in ie 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

we have a page having span tags with different widths. Initially in ie11 the widths weren't properly set. Hence we added the following css change to orient it correctly and **it worked**

```
span{
    display: inline-block;

}
```

but the same css change is not working properly for ie9 . We followed some SO suggestions and tried adding doctype but it didnt work out.

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried debugging more and found out the issue. Width in span was set in span without unit.

```
<span style='width:100'></span>
```

it was causing the error. After changing it to

```
<span style='width:100px'></span>
```

it worked in ie9 and ie11 .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a resetcss file before applying your own styles?
because every browser would have its on setting, the resetcss will basically reset all the default browser setting and then apply your setting, you can get this file online for free here is one on this link below:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
hope this helps, gud luck

Comment: thanks for your input Manam. I tried including resetcss.css . Still am not getting the effect.

Comment: is it possible for you to post your CSS? that way I can have a look at it?

Comment: Also have a look at this link below, it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482765/inline-block-firefox-4-vs-ie-9

Comment: thanks again. we already tried adding the doctype and it didnt work and our CSS file is too big to paste here. Is that fine if we paste only span related html and css stuffs ? or you want anything specific ?

Comment: if you can give me the related css, then I will try to have a look at it please?