# Is there a better solution than -moz-border-radius

Tags: css

I'm refactoring some pages put together by an old colleague and I can understand why he's left the company. I'm looking through his code and he's added -moz-border-radius:10 to an inline style. Okay this is great for Chrome and Firefox but how can I get this to work for IE? Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Mark?

Comment: IE9 supports this, you can use just `border-radius` for modern browsers. For older versions of IE you can use http://www.ccs3PIE.com

Comment: Bad link, correct one: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 support `border-radius` property, as well as Fx and Chrome. Use unprefixed name.

[Support for "border-radius" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

For older browsers that do not support even prefixed names, you can only use hacks as tables with images or so.

Answer (score 0):

IE 9, supports CSS 3 `border-radius`. If that's not what you're looking for, find `htc` files that implements `border-radius`.

Related post:

- [Support for “border-radius” in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

you should put all the vendor prefixes first, then the CSS3 equivalent.
In your case it would looke like this:

```
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
```

Internet Explorer 6,7,8 won't round corners, but this is ok from a progressive enhancement point of view. If it isn't ok from the client's point of view, you can either include a CSS based on CSS conditional statements and use a sprite with rounded corners or use a JavaScript fallback like http://css3pie.com/.

Older versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera will round corners because of the vendor prefix.

Good luck.