# border radius CSS in IE browser

Tags: html, css

I have a div with border radius, I write the CSS code for all the browsers:

```
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
```

but in IE it doesn't work!
What should I do?

Comment: research online. there are tons of solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using PIE.htc for all css3 styles will be better. I have used it in many of my projects and works fine in IE7/8/9.

Here is the link. http://css3pie.com/ This will provide you various demos for that and it is really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't no what happened... I change something in the page and the border disappeared! Do you know what?

Answer (score 2):

Border radius does not work in IE until version 9.

See: [Support for "border-radius" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

There are some suggestions on that answer as well as on Google for alternatives.

You **may** be required to use images for your rounded corners. You **may** be able to use a JavaScript based re-creation of rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IE8 or older, you have to do that with images or some sort of javascript plugin. If you're using IE9 or newer, then that code works perfectly fine.

Here are some jQuery plugins that could solve your problem: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/border-radius

Answer (score 0):

[Nifty Corners](http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html) works as well in IE8.

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/jCm7T/1/