# change background using css

Tags: css, magento

I am having a problem in this page:
xxx/printers/monochrome-laser-printers.html

I see the left column layered navigation is the red I want, but at the bottom some part is pink.
I changed a css class but it didnt change everything. I am not a very expert when detecting what css class I need to change.

I also need to change the Add to Cart button from pink background to the same red.

Any idea?

Comment: Most browser developer tools plugins let you click on a piece of the page and they'll pop up details about what you clicked on. Firebug, IE Dev Tools, Chrome, etc.. all allow this, and it's so useful it should be a crime for browsers to NOT provide the capability.

Comment: whats wrong with the marquee tag?

Comment: @MarcB I already know, I use it all the time, but I am not an expert on CSS and its hard to know exactly what to modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom part is pink because you're referencing this file as your background: http://www.theprinterdepot.net/skin/frontend/default/MAG060062/images/bot3.jpg

```
.block-layered-nav .block-content {
background: url(../images/bot3.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
background-color: #C9271F;
}
```

And your Add Cart button does the same:

```
button.button span {

background: transparent url(../images/bkg_btn.png) 0 0 no-repeat;

}
```

So you need to change your background images.

Comment: can you please check again, I cant make it work, now its blue and red instead of pink I want it all red.

Comment: It's blue now because you've also got it referencing this background: `.block .block-content { background-image: url(../images/bot2.jpg);}` - you would do better to do away with the backgrounds and if you want rounded corners just try to use `border-radius` like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie

Comment: If you remove the following lines from your CSS you'll get all red: Line 1: `background: url(../images/bot3.jpg)` and Line 2: `background-image: url(../images/bot2.jpg` BUT you will lose the rounded corners unless you start to use another method like `border-radius`

Answer (score -1):

Use F12 in your browser to see the CSS rules applied to those elements.  That should make it all clear.