# CSS3 Border-Radius and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, gradient, css

I have CSS3 gradient that I've generated with ColorZilla. I'm pretty sure what's causing the problem is the DATA URI. Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cY7Lp/.

In WebKit & Firefox, the corners are rounded as they should be, but in IE9, the corners are rounded and the gradient bleeds outside them, I don't want the gradient to bleed outside the corners. Does anybody know why it happens?

---Edit---

I forgot to mention, this does not happen with inline elements, only block elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your SVG image or its data URI, but it has to do with your `filter`. Effects generated by the `filter` property, which you're using, do not get clipped by `border-radius`, and often overlap certain other things such as background images.

Whether this is a real bug or an unintended side effect, I don't know, but that's the cause in IE9, as it doesn't implement CSS3 gradients — only IE10 does.

Since you're using an SVG image anyway, you can easily fall back to that instead of using `filter`.

Comment: Got it, The DATA URI Backup works with the radius but IE6-8 do not work with the DATA URI. Maybe if I reorder them?

Comment: @user1090389: Reordering won't work. Filters will always be drawn over your SVG background image.

Comment: Would it be drawn over -ms-linear-gradient?

Comment: PPS I forgot to mention, this does not happen with inline elements, only block elements.

Comment: Don't know about inline vs block elements, but yes, it won't work in IE10 either. If you're not bothering about older versions of IE, you can safely stop using filters altogether.

Comment: I'll have to decide when IE10 comes out

Answer (score 0):

Border radius issue seems to be discussed here:

[Support for "border-radius" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

... so, likely it is that your browser is rendering in legacy mode.

Comment: jsFiddle triggers standards mode.