# Use three div to create a banner round corner effect in css

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I want use three div to create a round effect,like

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left-corner"></div>
   <div class="center-repeat"></div>
   <div class="right-corner"></div>
</div>
```

the `.left-corner` and `.right-corner` have a only corner background image
css:

```
.wrapper
{
   width:100%
   height:110px;
}
.left-corner
{
   background:...
   width:110px;
   height:110px;
   float:left
}
.right-corner
{
   background:...
   width:110px;
   height:110px;
   float:right
}
```

but how should I render the middle div
I tried use `width:100%` but the corner div will be push and become another row
how can I set the three div in a line and look normal?

Comment: Wouldn't the `border-radius` property work? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: @NADH this is a great alternative, but you know as well as I that only newer browsers support this.  If it's imperative to the OP's design, he may not want the possibility of a sharp corner in his image(s).  +1 for pointing it out though.

Comment: do your corners have transparent area?

Comment: And in your code above, you have 2 classes of `left-corner`.  Hopefully this is a typo on this site and not in actual CSS.  If it is, you will need to fix it in your code or you will never get it to work properly

Comment: @JT Smith:that's an error the other is right-corner

Comment: @Candy:No I want the header fill of the page

Comment: i mean your corner image, is there any transparent part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `wrapper` is set in percentages, then I would think it best to keep it's children in percentages as well, perhaps use a 33%, 33% and 34% to get the 100%.  For the middle, or `center-repeat` I think you may need to use `float: left` as well, so it snugs up to the `left-corner`.

Comment: @NikhilBaliga:the example you give to me have a problem:the left-corner and right-corner doesn't fixed,the background image I give to it is a fixed size image, no repeat

Comment: @Candy Good point, then perhaps the middle should be a 100%, to fill the difference between the two sides?

Comment: @NikhilBaliga Thanks for helping with the fiddle.  I was trying to make one but couldn't think of images to use... Didn't consider using background color to show the alignment.  Thanks. +1

Comment: @hh54188 then what is the fixed width of your images?  You provided little information in your example above.  The fiddle is meant to show the relative alignment of your 3 divs, which it does.  Using those general guidelines, you should be able to align all 3 of your divs, regardless if they are all fixed width or relative.  If you need fixed width of your divs, then use your `px` but as it shows, using the floats as they are should give your the results you seek.  And if your images are fixed width, perhaps you should use a fix width container as well?  It will help with your layout breaking

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using border-radius property?


You can just use the center div and border radius any other corner.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius

[Support for "border-radius" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    ... content inside wrapper ... 
</div>

.wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This will work, but as I mentioned above in my comment, it won't work except in modern browsers.  The other issue I have had with this in the past is if your entire CSS isn't written in CSS3 then using `border-radius` it will fail validation, if this is a concern for the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i thing you should this

**Css**

```
.wrapper
{
   width:100%
   height:110px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid 5px black;
    border-radius:25px;
}
.left-corner
{
   background:red;
   width:110px;
   height:110px;
   float:left
}
.right-corner
{
   background:green;
   width:110px;
   height:110px;
   float:right
}


.center-corner{
width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    height:110px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="left-corner">Left</div>
    <div class="right-corner">Right</div>
    <div class="center-corner">Center</div>    
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/pTxrW/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7D9TV/4/).
Left and right corners are 10px less height than center block so it's easier to see borders between them.