# border radius in css

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, border

I am fetching a problem during fix the browser compatibility issue in IE8. 
I use the following code:

```
input[type="submit"],input[type="reset"] {
    border:0px;
    /*background-image:url(../images/button.jpg);*/
    background-color:#3778aa;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:79px;
    height:27px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    behavior: url(../images/ie-css3.htc); 
}
```

and "ie-css3.htc" file place in the right place. But still the curve for IE8 is not working. Please help me out.

Comment: Do you absolutely need border-radius in IE8? It's okay for browsers to render differently and border-radius is probably one of the least noticeable styles to drop

Comment: I dont  think it will work in IE8 , have a look at this [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the `behaviour` property, but maybe the [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) javascript library would do the job for you:

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Comment: thanks for your idea. Let check me whether it is working or not

Answer (score 4):

use [CSS#PIE](http://css3pie.com/) and follow the instruction. its support Internet Explorer 6-9

Answer (score 0):

[CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) is the solution of border-radius for IE8 and its previous versions.