# Border around Input Number?

Tags: html, css, input

I am trying to put a border around it, but i can't. Here is what i have as far as CSS:

```
body{ margin:1em; }
body *{ font-family: RussellSquare}
body{background-color: #363636;}

input[type=number]{
    font-size:1em;
    width:2.5em;
    padding:3px;
    margin:0;
    border-radius:3px; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}

input[type=number]:focus{
    outline:none;
}​
```

Comment: works here... (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fNH5q/) Chrome 20 Dev

Comment: What do you mean it can't?  If you are testing on IE, up until IE9 there's no support.

Comment: why does it cut off the border-radius?

Comment: It [Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/fNH5q/1/). In which browser (versions) are you experiencing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine. Try it yourself on different browsers [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eUQtU/).

Short explanation would be:

`border` is CSS property that is supported on all major browsers.

`border-radius` is CSS3 property that runs on all modern browsers. IE 6/7/8 **is not** one of them.

In case you want to know more about Internet Explorer support of `border-radius`

Read: [Support for "border-radius" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)