# -webkit support in cross browsers

Tags: css, webkit, cross-browser, mozilla

I am using `-webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px;` for the radius of the div. It is working fine in chrome and sfari but not in Mozilla Firefox and IE8.
How I can resolve it

```
<div style="background-color:#f7f7f7; width:340px; height:175px; -webkit-border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;">
              <div style="padding-top:20px;text-align:center"><input name="email" type="text" class="required emailcheck" placeholder="Enter your email address" id="email" style="height:25px; width:200px;-moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; "></div>

              <div style="padding-top:20px;text-align:center"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"  class="required" style="height:25px; width:200px; -webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;"></div>


          </div>​
```

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/uHHLX/

Comment: -moz-border-radius should be working fine in Firefox

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/635851/1001563

Comment: Mozilla dropped support for `-moz-border-radius` after Firefox 12. Always use the unprefixed version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make it work unless you use images, or a behaviour htc file for rounded corners.

To check support for something, use caniuse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

To get rounded corners in IE8 and below check the following page:

http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

Though these solutions are less than ideal, they are the only way I'm afraid....

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and below doesnt support the border-radius(css3)
to work for mozilla and IE9 you might need to include
border-radius:5px;