# Internet explorer 9 and border-radius

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Support for “border-radius” in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

I can't get border-radius to work in IE in my project, so I created this simple html file to see if I'm missing something.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>border test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{background-color: #009de8;}
div{border: 2px solid red;border-radius: 5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Still, borders are anything but round, though IE9 is supposed to support border-radius property.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

Internet explorer, in general, goes into quirks-mode if no `DOCTYPE` tag is included, which will render pages in a somewhat unexpected way.

Add this html5 doctype tag at the beginning of your html document (first line) and it will work:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

and it should work.

Comment: THIS is the answer. The X-UA thing is a non-standard crutch for IE which is the most incompetent browser on the planet.

Comment: This applies to all browsers that have a quirks mode as well, which is to say all of them. IE just happens to have one that is so egregiously bad that it is the precise reason why it's so... bad.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Support for "border-radius" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

You need this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: Trick got done, will accept when system lets me. ty.

Comment: Does `border-radius` work if you instead declare a valid doctype?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: It should.

Comment: in my actual project I use valid doctype for html5, but it doesn't seem to work.. should it?

Comment: funny thing.. tried to validate my html with the meta tag from the answer and got:Validation Output: 1 Error

    Error Line 5, Column 52: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

Comment: The X-UA thing is a crutch for incompetent IE and not a standard way to do things. See Shahar's answer.

Comment: @AnPel Who cares if it validates when it *works*? But better use `<!doctype html>` because it turns **all** browsers, not just IE, into standards mode.