# IE 8 border radius not working

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Support for “border-radius” in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

I have a problem while creating a website in IE

```
-moz-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:8px;
```

Is there any way to implement `border-radius` in IE 8?
And does anyone know how to implement the transparency of border?

Comment: i put this but not working in IE 8 and before ...

Comment: You put what into ie8 before? The other question? You'll find the answers you need in that other question -- this has been covered frequently on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cobble the border-radius on using an .htc file. I'd go with CSS3PIE - http://css3pie.com/ but there are others available - http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc

Upload the file to your server to the websites root, then in any CSS selector with border-radius applied add this

```
behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc);
```

**NOTE:**

Due to some classic Microsoft guff, .htc files paths must point to the root of the server. They are **NOT** relative to the CSS file.

Comment: Yeah this will fix that. Just follow the instructions in the answer.

Comment: for which version it support of IE

Comment: Not 100% but I think it goes as far back as 6 if you're still supporting that.

Comment: and about the border transparency  ??

Comment: I can't comment without seeing more of your code. Just try it. If it doesn't work make a separate question but this will solve the border-radius issue.

Comment: thanks man ...
about my code i'm using this code for opacity
 background-clip: padding-box;

    background-color: #FFFFFF;

    border: 5pt solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;

    color: #BBBBBB;

    height: auto;

    max-width: 800px;

Comment: If it's still an issue set it up as a new question, you'll get more help that way...

Answer (score 0):

IE8 don't support border-radius: so you may try http://css3pie.com/