# Border radius for all browser?

Tags: css

I use

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;    
border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-khtml-border-radius:5px;
```

for border radius but that code block not working some browser (internet explorer of course). I tried to use .htc but I had no success.

How can I make `border-radius` that is supported by all browsers?

Comment: Anyone finding this through a search, see also related [Support for “border-radius” in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

Answer (score 8):

The border-radius property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera, because it is CSS3 property. The syntax is:

```
border-radius: 1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%;
```

Example 1

```
border-radius:2em;
```

is equivalent to:

```
border-top-left-radius:2em;
 border-top-right-radius:2em;
 border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
 border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
```

Example 2

```
border-radius: 2em 1em 4em / 0.5em 3em;
```

is equivalent to:

```
border-top-left-radius: 2em 0.5em;
 border-top-right-radius: 1em 3em;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4em 0.5em;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em 3em;
```

See more detailed explanation and tips and tricks for border radius [here](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers).