# GWT-CheckBox: rounded edges

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt2

How could i add curved corner to a gwt-checkbox using css?

```
.gwt-CheckBox {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

This Doesn't works!!!!

i also tried this too. but no change.

```
.gwt-CheckBox > input {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

spell check - `border-redius must be border-radius`
Curved Corner for checkbox via CSS is possible only in firefox/chrome and not in IE8 browser.

Which browser are you testing on? Apart from IE for others try -moz-border-radius or -webkit-border-radius etc depending on your browser.

Refer the link for IE information- [Support for "border-radius" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)