# Rounded Corner Controls CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

I have implemented a rounded corner control using css ,it is displayed correctly in firefox but not in IE 10 can anyone point out the change I need to make it working in both.I saw some answers pointing to add pie.htc to the css folder ,I tried that as well

```
.DropDownList
{
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Tried adding overflow:hidden ,it makes it not appear in Firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3782946/1661238), you might need to inspect your X-UA-Compatible tag and make sure you aren't referencing a previous version of IE:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

(Border radius support started with IE9).

Comment: If I specify ie=9 the website appears different and if I specify ie=edge nothing happens,there is a rounded corner in the background but the drop downlist is a square above it.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at this page:
http://geekswithblogs.net/ihaynes/archive/2012/09/16/ie10---be-prepared.aspx

I claims that IE10 can enter 'compatibility mode' while developing ASP.Net locally and provides a workaround.

> If you locally preview a site  that uses HTML5 and CSS3 features
>   (placeholder text, round corners etc) in IE10, using the EW
>   Development Server or IIS, you may find that these features don't
>   display.
>
> This is because the default browser mode for intranet sites in IE10 is
>   'Compatibility mode'. You can change this in 'Tools - Compatibility
>   View Settings' . Uncheck the 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility
>   View' option.
>
> Now you'll notice that there is also a setting 'Display all websites
>   in Compatibility View'. What happens to your site if a user has this
>   checked, intentionally or unintentionally?  Your site won't display
>   properly.
>
> You can avoid this problem by forcing IE10 into it's highest or 'Edge'
>   mode. You do this by adding the following meta tag to your pages or
>   the DWT / ASP.Net MasterPage.
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
> ```
>
> It's worth adding this to the existing IE Meta Tag snippets in EW V4.

EDIT: Added relevant quote. (Corrected spelling of 'compatibility'.)

Comment: Specifically: “the default browser mode for intranet sites in IE10 is 'Compatibility mode'. You can change this in 'Tools - Compatibility View Settings' . Uncheck the 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' option.” (Just to protect against link rot. And correct the “Compatability” typo.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but i can't edit your comment :)
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compatible

Comment: Oh I know: in the linked article, they spell it incorrectly. I’ve corrected that in my comment.