# can't set rounded borders on tooltip menu

Tags: html, menu, html-lists, css

I am working with a menu tutorial found [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/23/tooltip-menu/) and everything works fine except i would like border corners.  I've tried setting them everywhere possible but nothing works.  any ideas on where it should work?

I've tried:

```
.cbp-tm-show .cbp-tm-submenu{
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

also:

```
.cbp-tm-show-below .cbp-tm-submenu{ border-radius: 5px; }
```

every possible place i've tried it and haven't seen any effect.. :(

Comment: what browser are you using?  see this question if its IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie

Comment: chrome, i've never had an issue with rounded borders before this is the first time and i'm assuming its something in the css in this tutorial thats keeping me from it.

Comment: @Andres You can use the Chrome DevTools to see if other CSS is affecting the element.

Comment: I've tried everything, disabling properties adding and haven't been able to figure it out.  Thats why I'm asking if someone else could take a look maybe I'm just missing something..you know how it is, work on it too long and u get lost..lol

Comment: We need a link to your site under construction or the code. If code, please strip it down to its essentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andres Try setting a background color on the ul element (.cbp-tm-show .cbp-tm-submenu). At the moment the background color is set to transparent (in the demo).

Answer (score 1):

As @Dean Stalker mentions, you need to set a background color on the submenu's `ul` element.  You also need to set padding or a border width > 0 to that same `ul` in order for `border-radius` to have something to "round off".

The below assumes the background color of the submenus is white, like in the demo you linked to:

```
.cbp-tm-submenu {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```