# HTML5 video tag in IE

Tags: css, html

I have used  video tag in my code

```
<div class="mask">                                   
  <video class="circleVideo" id="video" width="423" height="423" autoplay="autoplay" style="border-radius: 220px;">
    <source src="videoconv/loginVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="videoconv/loginVideo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="videoconv/loginVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

Here i have added some Css for the video and div.

```
        border-radius: 220px;
        height: 423px;
        width: 423px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 198px;
        right: -416px;
        background-color: rgba(255,163,25,0.3);
        -webkit-border-radius: 220px;
        -moz-border-radius: 220px;
        -ms-border-radius: 220px;
        -o-border-radius: 220px;
        /*clip: rect(1px, 423px, 423px, 0);*/
        -khtml-border-radius: 220px;
        -webkit-mask-image: url(../images/mask_img.png);
    }


    .circleVideo {
        width: 582px;
        border-radius: 220px;
        margin-top: -33px;
        margin-left: -74px;
        height: 488px;
    }
```

Here is the js I have added, which allows me to see this in IE:

`html5media.min.js`

I am not able to apply the css to the video in IE. It works correctly in chrome and firefox and opera.

What more should i do so that the video also appears in a circle in IE?

Answer (score 0):

IE can be tricky with border-radius, it appears someone had a similar issue: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

There are some workarounds for CSS3 compatibility pre-IE9, many will suggest [Modenizer](http://modernizr.com/) - a super easy method to try is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the IE version as recommended by @reto.

   **Note that border-radius does not exist in earlier versions of IE. You may have to write styling that targets earlier versions of IE, if you wish to support them.**
2. Inspect the element in IE to ensure the element you are styling actually exists.

Depending on how old the version of IE that you are working with is, I would recommend taking a progressive enhancement<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)</sup> approach.

## References

1. Progressive Enhancement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement